# how to use styledown with gulp?

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have task

```js
gulp.task('generate-styleguid',() => {
  'use strict';

  return gulp.src('./src/styleguid')
    .pipe(styledown({
      config: './src/styleguid/config.md ',
      filename: './src/styleguid/styleguide.html'
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./src/styleguid/'))
})
```

When I run it I'm getting an error:
**fs.js:646
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                 ^
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory**

[image: screen]

Can there be a problem with paths? And how to solve it?

Comment: You have an extra space in the path: `'./src/styleguid/config.md '`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extra space after `config.md` in your path.

The line **config: './src/styleguid/config.md ',** should be **config: './src/styleguid/config.md',**